# Decrease stalled time on page loading with sub domain resources

Tags: google-chrome, subdomain, page-load-time, stalled

Google chrome stall resource while downloading if there is already six connections with domain. I read on internet that to decrease stall time of resource, put resource on multiple domains so that more connections will download.

I want to know that separate domain is necessary or i can load resources from sub domain to decrease stalled time of resource to improve page loading time.